# Correct application of /= operator

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

For a giventest_images:

```
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
(training_images, training_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()
```

I can execute:

```
test_images=test_images/255.0
```

but can't execute:

```
test_images/=255.0
```

because of:

> TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting was
>   found for ufunc true_divide

I do not understand the error. Why and how to use this operator correctly in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue that is explained here: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/10565

Looks like you'll have to use `test_images = test_images / 255.0`

Comment: As that page explains, it's expected behavior, not a bug. It happens because the original array contains integers, but the result of `/` gives floats so it can't be stored in the same array.